# Is there a way to define the order in which functions are listed in the module html page?

Tags: doxygen

I have several functions declared in a header `.h` file and implemented in a `.c` file (C, not C++).

In the header file, I include "`@defgroup Gr1`" and, in the `.c` file, I include "`@addtogroup Gr1`", which makes both files contents belong to group `Gr1`.

I have observed (I don't know if it's always so) that, in the Doxygen generated html `Gr1` Module page, the functions get listed in the order in which they are implemented in the `.c` file. I would need them to be listed in a different, defined by me, order (in this case, it would be enough that they be listed in the .h file declaration order).

So, I have two questions:

1.- Is there any way to define that functions listing order?

2.- Is there any way to make their listing order be the `.h` file declaration order?

(if possible, I would prefer not to edit the layout xml file, as I would like to directly use the documentation generated by Doxygen every time I make some changes to the code).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the only control you have over the listing order -- without changing the source code -- is to switch between alphabetical and declaration order.  (The various `SORT_*` options in the config file control this.)

If you leave alphabetical sorting *off*, you could generate docs that follow the order given in the header file by moving your `@addtogroup` into the header file.  This doesn't have to be very invasive: you can add a whole sequence of declarations at once with curly braces.

```
/**
 * @addtogroup my_group
 * @{
 */

...declarations here...

/** }@ */
```

As an aside, you mentioned not wanting to edit the `layout.xml` file because it would add extra steps to your workflow.  I've had good luck with placing the modified layout in a file called `DoxygenLayout.xml` right next to my `Doxyfile` configuration; doxygen will automatically pick that up and use it.  That said, I don't believe editing the layout file will help you here.